# How to set the preloadedState in redux toolkit (with typescript)?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

At the moment I'm doing this

```
export let store = null;

export default function getStore(incomingPreloadState?: any) {
  store = configureStore({
    reducer: { 
      content: ContentSlice
    },
    preloadedState: incomingPreloadState,
  });
  return store;
}
export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>
export type AppDispatch = typeof store.dispatch
```

Obviously, I'm getting the error that the store could possibly be null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot more going on here. You probably don't want that module-global `store` variable that would always be "the last store created" - at least I wouldn't recommend that, as you could end up with mixing up multiple store instances that way.

To get the right type for the store, you'll have to call `combineReducers` manually.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  content: ContentSlice
})

export default function getStore(incomingPreloadState?: AppState) {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    preloadedState: incomingPreloadState,
  });
  return store;
}
export type AppState = ReturnType<typeof rootReducer>
export type AppDispatch = ReturnType<typeof getStore>['dispatch']
```